# If $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles and right-angle, with $AB=AC=x$ and $M,N$ are the midpoints of $AC$ and $AB$ respectively, find the area of $MON$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

If $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles and right-angle, with $AB=AC=x$ and $M,N$ are the midpoints of $AC$ and $AB$ respectively, find the area of $\triangle MON$

[image]

My solution goes as follows, If $D$ is a point on $CB$ such that $MD\perp CB$, we have that the area of $\triangle CMB$ is $\frac{x^2}{4}$. Hence $\frac{MD*x\sqrt{2}}{2}=\frac{x^2}{4}$ we then from this find the height of $\triangle COB$ and $\triangle AMN$, and since we also have the height of $\triangle CAB$ from $CB$, so from this we get the height of $\triangle MON$ and hence we have that its area is $\frac{x^2}{24}$. My solution is very long and tedious, is there a faster and easier approach to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the triangles $OMN$ and $OBC$ are similar with $\frac{ON}{OC}=\frac12$. Then
$$[OMN]= \frac{ON^2}{OC^2}[OBC]=\frac14\cdot \frac23 [NBC]= \frac16\cdot\frac12[ABC]=\frac1{24}x^2
$$

Answer (score 1):

Another potential solution (which may or may not be faster or easier) involves directly looking at the height of $\triangle MON$ with base $MN$. Let $D$ be the midpoint of $BC$. Then $AD$ passes through $O$ and is also an altitude, because $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles.

Since the centroid splits each median in a $2:1$ ratio, we have that $AO = \frac{2}{3}h$. Now, let $T$ be the intersection of $AO$ and $MN$. Then we have $OT \perp MN$. Furthermore, by similar triangles, we see that $AT = \frac{1}{2}h$. So, $OT = \frac{1}{6}h$.

Since $MN = h = \frac{x\sqrt{2}}{2}$, $$ [MON] = \frac{1}{2}(MN)(OT) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{x\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{x\sqrt{2}}{2} = \frac{x^2}{24}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Medians of a triangle intersect each other at $2/3$ of their length: $CO=BO=2OM=2ON$.

Hence, if $a$ is the area of $MON$, then the area of $COM$ and $BON$ is $2a$ and the area of $BOC$ is $4a$. Adding those areas together we thus get:
$$
9a={3\over4}\cdot{x^2\over2},
\quad\text{that is:}\quad
a={x^2\over24}.
$$